# Process stdin with two process

Tags: terminal, stdin, keystroke, tee

I want to implement an overlay for terminal (to see keystrokes on a terminal session) based on [Implement overlay in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694525/implement-overlay-in-terminal)

That was just a proof of concept what I really want is to convert input to keystrokes: Ctrl+, , , 1-9, a-z, A-Z, etc

Is there any way to process input normally and render keystrokes to stdout?

Basically I want to reimplement tee

https://superuser.com/a/557291/158200

So stdin goes to /dev/pts/ (terminal) but to my program too.

As I write this I feel that my two process involved are bash and my new program but don't know where stdin comes from

Seems whatever `script` does will be the answer, but isolating only stdin https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200642/23369

Comment: Have you not thought of [showkey](https://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey) ? also, asking for recommendations on library is frowned upon, read the [FAQ].

Comment: When you say "dup all stdin input to a file" do you mean you want to keep stdin as it is, and save a copy of it in a file? You can't do that with dup, you have to do it yourself

Comment: Also, stick to one question per post, it's hard to tell what the ideal answer would be here